# What NoSQL database use to store complex objects?

Tags: database, postgresql, object, nosql

I don't know much about **NoSQL** database, but with some research, I think it can improve and solve the problems I'm having.

I have a principal complex object in my program called `Page`. It has various `TextBlock` that has various `Token`.

I don't need individual operations on these objects, but I need the entire object, the `Page`.

I need to process all objects stored in database and there is a lot of then (to millions). Retrieving the objects in a RMDB is very slow, I think that a NoSQL database will solve my necessity, but I don't know what to use.

*At the moment, I'm using PostgreSQL.*
**What NoSQL database can I use to store complex objects and can be used with Java?**

Comment: Any DB (sql or nosql) can store a "complex" object once it's been serialized into a text-like format - it'd just be a text/blob field like any other.

Comment: Before you start changing your database you should find out *why* "retrieving the objects" is slow and whether a noSQL database will improve it. I use SQL databases with >100 000 000 records and retrieving data is not what makes it slow.

Comment: @Dour High Arch Appears to be slow because I'm trying to recover all the data in a sequential way with a CURSOR, and it does a JOIN in 3 tables to this. You can see better in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200134/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-an-object-that-is-split-into-three-tables-with-only-on

Comment: You are correct that SQL cursors are very slow. Investigate eliminating the use of cursors before you decide to change databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any NoSQL database can store your object by using a serializing method. Normally NoSQL database work handy when you know which object you have to retrieve from the database,  If you need to have some query on your data think about CouchDB (or Couchbase) or MongoDB which use json like document to save data and gives you querying ability with different pros and cons. Select the one you according to your requirement.